# Yellow Box Errors/Warnings after React Native Upgrade

Tags: css, react-native

I recently upgraded my project from React Native 0.15 to 0.20. I guess this was kind of a leap and I'm quite new to these Yellow Box Warnings. Right now I got 2 warnings as follows.

**Warning One:**

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined,
>   boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a
>   ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of
>   ItemViewPage.

**Warning Two:**

> View #2359 of type RCTView has a shadow set but cannot calculate
>   shadow efficiently. Consider setting a background color to fix this,
>   or apply the shadow to a more specific component.

Figured out that **Warning One** was due to using `const Radio = require('react-native-simple-radio-button');` instead of `import Radio from 'react-native-simple-radio-button';`. Once the change was done, **Warning One** was gone.

For the **Warning Two**, the page it sends it from has place where it uses shadows.

**Styling Code:**

```
container: {
    overflow: 'hidden',
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)',
    shadowColor: '#000000',
    shadowOpacity: 1,
    shadowRadius: 20,
    shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: -5},
    justifyContent: 'center'
}
```

**Code:**

```
renderItem: function (item) {
    var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
    return (
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="rgba(0,0,0,0)" style={styles.buttonFill}
                                onPress={this.categoryPressed.bind(this, item.categoryId, item.name)}>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <KenBurnsImage tension={6} friction={50} imageWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width} imageHeight={Dimensions.get('window').height / 100 * 30} sourceUri={{uri: item.image}} placeholderSource={{uri: './images/placeholder.jpg'}}/>
                    <View>
                        <LinearGradient
                            colors={[processColor('rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)'), processColor('rgba(0,0,0,0)'), processColor('rgba(0,0,0,0.7)')]}
                            style={styles.linearGradient}>
                            <View style={styles.allContent}>
                                <View style={styles.imageRowContainer}>
                                    <View style={styles.nameContainer}>
                                        <Text style={styles.textMain}>{item.name}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    {this._renderItemCountSection(item.itemsCount)}
                                    <View style={styles.continueContainer}>
                                        <Text style={styles.textArrow}>&#xf105;</Text>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </LinearGradient>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>

        </View>
    );
}
```

`renderItem` function is rendering items from the `ListView`.

As the code states, it already has the Background Color. So why is this warning coming? What is the fix? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've reproduced your example and it doesn't throw an error for me. Can you give us a bit more of your code ?

Comment: Could you also include the JSX where you are applying this style? And also the its Parent JSX and the style

Comment: @G.Hamaide Added the JSX code where the style is being used.

Comment: @AakashSigdel Added the JSX code.

Comment: OK, thx. Still, I don't have a warning raised here. If you remove the Linear Gradient, is the warning still here ?

Comment: I reproduced the warning you said and have added the answer for it.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77149489/9570734

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because you are setting the `backgroundColor` as transparent `rgba(255, 255, 255 ,0.0)`. This is very inefficient. You can read all about this in this commit log
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/e4c53c28aea7e067e48f5c8c0100c7cafc031b06

Comment: Thanks. This was the root cause.

Comment: How to have a shadow on a **border radius** with `overflow:hidden` then? Now i am forced to have another layer of container just for the shadow because `overflow:hidden` will clip the shadow. Which btw, will cause this error because the container wouldn't have any background color to it

Comment: Solved my problem in my case adding the background color to the view. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

**For warning two**

In my case, I deleted shadowOpacity, added it to the shadow color and used RGBA value.

```
shadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.1)'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working on a view with a border radius by applying all styles to the same `View` and removing `overflow:hidden`. Also note that I separated the shadow styles for iOS and Android.

```js
    cardContainer: {
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
      borderRadius: 4,
    },
    shadowAndroid: {
      elevation: 2,
    },
    shadowIos: {
      shadowColor: 'rgba(16, 24, 40, 0.08)',
      shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
      shadowOpacity: 1,
      shadowRadius: 2,
    },

// ...

const shadowStyle = Platform.select({
    ios: styles.shadowIos,
    android: styles.shadowAndroid,
})

return <View style={[styles.cardContainer, shadowStyle]}>{children}</View>
```