# view has a shadow set but cannot calculate shadow efficiently

Tags: react-native

I'm getting this error message:

```
>View #54 of type RCTView has a shadow set but cannot calculate shadow efficiently.
```

The error message is clear, except that I don't know which view is `#54`?!?

Is there a way to figure out to which view react native is referring to with this numbering system?

Comment: Please look at this question <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618620/yellow-box-errors-warnings-after-react-native-upgrade>!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are setting the `backgroundColor` as transparent `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)`. This is very inefficient. You can read all about this in this commit log https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/e4c53c28aea7e067e48f5c8c0100c7cafc031b06

You can delete `shadowOpacity`, add it to the shadow color, and use an RGBA value.

```
shadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.1)'
```